# Working with dropdownList and TextBox in Asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, textbox

How do you add values to a database using a dropdownList or a TextBox without using a button in asp.net C# application?

Comment: Please provide details of your code and the point where you are facing an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set AutoPostBack property to true and save it on index changed event.

```html
<asp:DropDownList   
         ID="DropDownList1"  
         runat="server"  
         AutoPostBack="true"  
         OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"  
         >  
         <asp:ListItem>option1</asp:ListItem>  
         <asp:ListItem>option2</asp:ListItem> 

</asp:DropDownList>
```

```cs
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)  
{  
     //save data here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For drop down list, its simple. Set the "AutoPostBack" property for it as "true". And handle the "SelectedIndexChanged" event like shown below.

```
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)  
    {  
      //save data here
    }
```

But for textbox you have a server side event "TextChanged", which you can use the same way by setting "AutoPostBack" to "true" for the textbox as well.

```
    protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)  
    {  
      //do something here
    }
```

The drawback with this textbox event is it gets fired with every keystroke.

So its not good for handling the database operation with every keystroke.

jQuery & an invisible button can help.

Have an asp Button, set its visibility to false. Handle its click event on the server side like shown below.

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)  
    {  
      ////save data here
    }
```

For your text box wire up a jQuery .blur() event like shown below & fire the click event of the hidden button from it.

```
    $("#TextBox1").blur(function() {
      $("#Button1").click();
    });
```

This would fire the button click event on server side, when you stop editing textbox value. Do your database operation from the button click event on server side.

Answer (score -1):

I think you could implement it through a page load event

Comment: This doesn't provide an answer - it's currently worded more as a guess than anything else. Elaborate what you think is a viable solution.